# How to configure build input packages/dependencies within Nix development shells?

Tags: alsa, nix, nixpkgs, bevy, pipewire

I'm not using NixOS but I wrote a flake that I'm using to generate a dev shell to build a [Rust project](https://gist.github.com/nothingnesses/f28c625fada32d2002d3d245309989b7) (this is essentially just [the audio example](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/97d8e4e1793ede3df8c77ed44736e800b38ff7a4/examples/audio/audio.rs) from the Bevy repository). My issue is that I encounter the following error when attempting to run the project in the dev shell:

```
$ nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command --extra-experimental-features flakes develop
bash-4.4$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 6.62s
     Running `target/debug/audio`
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NoDevice', /home/a/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bevy_audio
-0.5.0/src/audio_output.rs:22:67
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
bash-4.4
```

One of the dependencies of the project is the Bevy crate which requires ALSA, so I'm assuming the issue is because the ALSA package exposed by the dev shell is probably misconfigured. I use PipeWire on my actual system (I think it also uses ALSA as a backend) and I tried adding ALSA and PipeWire as one of the buildInputs for the flake, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to configure these within the dev shell. According to [this issue on the Bevy repository](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/2705), the usual fix for this issue, at least for Arch-based distros, is to install the pipewire-alsa package. I'm not sure what the equivalent of doing that is in the context of a Nix dev shell is though, since there is no pipewire-alsa package in nixpkgs that I can add to my flake. So with that said, how should I go about configuring ALSA or PipeWire in the dev shell?

Comment: This is not exactly my forte, but since your issue is running and not building, and since pipewire is a system service, I assume you have to install the missing package with your system package manager, not Nix.

Comment: Thanks. PipeWire is already installed on my system and works (audio works on Firefox and VLC). I'm not sure how to make the dev shell use the PipeWire installed on my system though.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to fix this yet, but for posterity, this GitHub comment about how to make derivations use native libraries seems like it might be useful: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9415#issuecomment-139655485.